# I can't launch a jupyter notebook in anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda in my work PC but I can't launch a jupyter notebook.

When launching a notebook, it tries to open it with windows media player instead of with Internet explorer.

Also, when I open the browser and enter the IP http://127.0.0.1:8888, it asks for a token or password.

It only happens on the PC of my work, on my usual PC it works

Comment: Try this:  Open `anaconda prompt` and type `jupyter notebook`

Comment: You can use `jupyter notebook list` to see all jupyter instances running and for each get a link that contains the token.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method :
[Anaconda Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMPaC.png)

Try to type "jupyter notebook" in Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: Thanks! You have helped me to solve the problem. It was that the documents HTML was linked to Windows media player instead Internet Explorer. I have chnged it in the settings of Windows 10